# How to make servlet thread safe in distributed environment?

Tags: multithreading, servlets

I know how to make thread safe in non distributed environment , but I want to know how to make Servlet thread safe in distributed environment ? Because one Servlet instance will be created per JVM by Servlet container and how to make them thread safe?

Thanks in Advance

Rajesh

Comment: What made you think that having Servlet per JVM will violate threadsafe? Aren't those two different things?

Answer (score 1):

Servlets that are running on different JVM instances do not have to worry about being thread safe since they don't share any resources.

The normal practices for making any code thread safe apply to servlets in the same JVM.  For example, don't modify shared resources without making them synchronized and make use of java.util.concurrent classes, use thread local storage, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Any code is said to be `Not Thread Safe` if there will be concurrency issues when that piece of code is executed by different threads.

In Distributed Environment, there is no way two threads from different JVM can access the servlet instance.